# Why do I get the error Map is not defined using Google's V8 engine?

Tags: javascript, v8, embedded-v8

Hi I am willing to embedded MathJax for an applicaton I am developing. I chose V8 as the JS engine but I am having problem loading MathJax.

The issue I get is that "Map" is undefined. Shouldn't this be a standard JavaScript built-in object?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <v8.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

v8::Handle< v8::Value > include( const v8::Arguments & args ) {
   for ( int i = 0; i < args.Length(); i++ )
   {
      v8::String::Utf8Value str( args[ i ] );

      std::string js_file;
      std::ifstream in_file( *str );
      if ( in_file )
      {
         std::ostringstream ofs;
         ofs << in_file.rdbuf();
         js_file = ofs.str();
      }

      if( js_file.length() > 0 ) {
         v8::Handle< v8::String > source = v8::String::New( js_file.c_str() );
         v8::Handle< v8::Script > script = v8::Script::Compile( source );
         return script->Run();
      }
   }

   return v8::Undefined();
}


int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {

   v8::V8::Initialize();
   v8::Isolate * isolate = v8::Isolate::New();

   {
      // Create a stack-allocated isolate scope.
      v8::Isolate::Scope isolate_scope( isolate );

      // Create a stack-allocated handle scope.
      v8::HandleScope handle_scope;

      v8::Handle< v8::ObjectTemplate > global = v8::ObjectTemplate::New();
      global->Set( v8::String::New( "include" ), v8::FunctionTemplate::New( include ) );

      // Create a new context.
      v8::Handle< v8::Context > context = v8::Context::New( NULL, global );
      // Enter the created context
      v8::Context::Scope context_scope( context );

      v8::Handle< v8::String > source = v8::String::New(
         "include( \"/home/elias/mathjax/es5/tex-mml-svg.js\" )"
      );

      // Compile the source code.
      v8::Handle< v8::Script > script = v8::Script::Compile( source );

      // Run the script to get the result.
      v8::Handle< v8::Value > result = script->Run();

      // Convert the result to an ASCII string and print it.
      v8::String::AsciiValue ascii( result );
      printf( "%s\n", * ascii );
   }
   // Dispose the isolate and tear down V8.
   isolate->Dispose();
   v8::V8::Dispose();

   return 0;
}
```

Above you can see the code I am using. I had even to implement the include() function, which seems to be present when scripts are run in browsers.

I was imagining that it could be possible to run any scrpit using V8, but it seems not to be the case.

Comment: Hey, which runtime environment are you using? Node.js, Chrome?

Comment: I am runnnig V8 standalone from a c++ program.

Comment: I edited the question and added an example code.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing `#include <v8.h>` make me guess that you're using the libv8-dev package on Ubuntu, which for a long time was V8's 3.14 branch, dating back to the year 2012. `Map` was added to the standard in EcmaScript 2015 (aka ES6) and shipped in V8's 3.28 branch in 2014.

I recommend that you get a recent V8 version (8.3 [would be a good choice right now](https://v8.dev/docs/version-numbers)) from [v8.dev](https://v8.dev/docs/source-code).

Comment: You are right, this was the problem. I wasn't expecting it to be that outdated. I had to redo a large part of the code, but it now knows what Map is and MathJax seems to be loading properly.